# How to calculate the energy required to rotate a planet?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, mass, rotational-dynamics

How to calculate the energy required to rotate a planet from non-rotating state? Say the planet is Venus with equally distributed mass of $4.8676 \times 10^{24}$ kg, and desired rate of 1 rotation per 24 hours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [rotational energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational_energy) of a body is given by:

$$ E = \tfrac{1}{2}I\omega^2 $$

where $I$ is the [moment of inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia) and $\omega$ is the [angular velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity). For a uniform sphere the moment of inertia is related to the mass of the sphere, $m$, and the radius of the sphere, $r$, by:

$$ I = \frac{2}{5}mr^2 $$

You already have the mass, and you can Google for the radius of Venus. That will give you everything you need to answer the question.